# How to create a connection between two objects, reference to one and to many in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have two classes

```
class Role
{ 
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class Permission
{ 
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a table for assign multiple permission to a role

```
class RoleAssignedPermissions
{ 
    string Id { get; set; }
    Role Role { get; set; }
    ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

In `OnModelCreating` I have:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            });
modelBuilder.Entity<Permission>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            });
modelBuilder.Entity<RoleAssignedPermissions>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
                entity.HasOne(x => x.Role);                    
                entity.HasMany(x => x.Permissions);
            });
```

In this case is by adding a migration are generated three tables, roles table is ok with id and name

But `Permissions` instead of id and name, appear new column `RoleAssignedPermissionsId`, and in table `RoleAssignedPermissions` id and roleId

But should be in `RoleAssignedPermissions` a column for collection of `Permissions`

Comment: Any specific reason why you can't have an ICollection<Permission> in Role Table only, that way, your code will be simple and one less table to maintain.

Comment: @Alex the third table is basically used for many-to-many relations. If you want to have multiple permission against a role then roleId should go to the permission table and there will be a collection of permission in the role.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the entities. You can do like this

```
class Role
{ 
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions {get; set;}
}

class Permission
{ 
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public string RoleId {get; set;}
    public virtual Role Role {get; set;}
}
```